# Params hash in initialize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR and building a new controller, I tried to get the :id from the params hash in the initialize method of the controller, but rails is coming back saying that it's a method... Everywhere I've read it's a hash so why the NoMethod error?

Anyway the main thing that has me stumped is why I can't access the params hash (or method or whatever it is :) ) from the initialize method?

Really appreciate any help with this...

Thanks :)

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def initialize
    if params[:id] && !params[:id].empty
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end 
  end

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and a screenshot of the error is here: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/6063/screenshot20110423at221.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a `before_filter` to get the result you are looking for:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_person

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def show
    # @person is already set from the before_filter
    # @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def find_person
    if params[:id] && !params[:id].blank?
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for that... appreciate it

Comment: Do u think this way of doing it is better or the 'inherited_resources' gem?

Comment: The `inherited_resources` gem does something similar, I have used it before, but eventually I end up re-implementing more application specific versions of that functionality over time. So I would say `inherited_resources` is a great start for development and prototyping.

Comment: but now that method is firing all the time but initialize run only once right ?

Answer (score 0):

Because *initialize* is called when the class is created. At this point, I imagine the request hasn't been processed yet.  It might work better if you called `super` first,  but I don't think Rails applications normally use the class initializer.

Comment: Ok, but is params a hash or a method? What is it?

Comment: **1.** It's Hash-like.  The Ruby interface is deliberately vague, at some level of abstraction everything just responds to messages. Some of the messages are built-in. **2.** `super` is the *initialize* method in the parent class, or *superclass*.  By defining an *initialize* you intercept the call that would have gone to initialize in the superclass, but a method call to *super* from your initialize will invoke the parent's.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `before_filter`, might be more what you are looking for.

---

Example for my comment

```
def foo
  {:hello => "world", :foo => "bar"}
end

foo[:hello] # => "world"
foo[:foo]   # => "bar"
```

Comment: Yup, I have seen the before_filter but I don't get why params is not in initialize, as it's defined in the routes???

Comment: well there is a difference between initialize and when a request is made. Before a request is made the controller will have already been loaded and initialized. For you to get params, you will need to make an actual request first.

Comment: OK, but is params a hash or a method?

Comment: I have not see the source for params, but by the way you access it I assume it's a method that returns a hash.

Comment: well if you return a hash via a method you can use that method (as the hash itself) to get hash values. I'll put an example in my post.

Comment: Ah, ok... thanks for posting the example... really appreciate it!